# Irrelevant type in nested generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Using a generic into a generic method, forces you to add the type parameter of the generic in the method, too although it might be irrelevant.

Adding the parameter also causes a code analysis warning:
    CA1004: Generic methods should provide type parameter

Is there a way of ignoring the type when it is not relevant?

Example:

```
public void Method<TUseful, TIrrelevant>(TUseful genericObject) where TUseful : UsefulConcrete<TIrrelevant>
```

I have also tried:

```
public void Method<TUseful>(TUseful genericObject) where TUseful : UsefulConcrete<object> // With UsefulConcrete<in/out T>
```

And:

```
public void Method<TUseful>(TUseful genericObject) where TUseful : UsefulConcrete<>
```

But it doesn't help.

Comment: You need rank-2 polymorphism to do this which C# doesn't support.

Comment: @Lee Useful comment; I suggest you read something about SOLID principles.

Answer (score 1):

[`CA1004`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182150.aspx) is just a warning telling it's impossible to infer generic types of your method directly from the method parameters. You will have to explicitly provide the types when calling it :

```
this.Method<Type1,Type2>(someObject);
```

You can just ignore this warning and use your method as it, or add parameters with corresponding generic types in your method parameters.

In your specific case, I would prefer to create a base non-generic class for `UsefulConcrete<>`, and constraint `TUseful` on it :

```
public void Method<TUseful>(TUseful genericObject) where TUseful : UsefulConcrete
```

Comment: I cannot use a base interface/class, the "irrelevant type" is irrelevant, but not useless. I need to call a method on the TUseful which returns a TIrrelevant. (I don't need it into that funcion, but it's propagated to another function inside).

Comment: CA1004 is a code analysis warning, not a compiler warning, and not a compiler error. Why not explicitly call your method with explicit types and just ignore this analysis warning ?

Comment: I was wondering whether the warning was right and I was doing something wrong; Also, I didn't know whether you could not specify a nested type for a generic.

Comment: As it's described in MSDN, you have to specify the nested type explicitly. Looking at the "When to Suppress Warnings" chapter, you will understand it's a recommendation for better readability and usage of your code. That's all. Nothing forbids you to write your method call with explicit types.

Answer (score 0):

The `TIrrelevant` type parameter is very relevant. Without this parameter you are not able to create `UsefulConcrete` generic class.

If you know the type parameter for `UsefulConcrete` just use it: `UsefulConcrete<MyType>`

Comment: than you have to promote it to derived class. Otherwise there is no way how to express your wishes about the type.

Comment: I was looking for a pattern to avoid downcasting, but I guess there is no way to achieve it.